# React - use window.open to open a URL from a variable

Tags: reactjs, window.open

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but I'm just trying to have a URL entered into a field and then a button that, when clicked, will take the value in that field and open a new tab to that URL.
If I do this:

```
    onClick={event => {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
    }}
```

Then it works just fine and opens a new tab with the specified url.

But if I set urlText = "https://www.google.com/" and do this:

```
onClick={event => {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   window.open({urlText},'_blank');
}}
```

Then it opens a new tab, but it goes to this instead:

http://theCurrentWebsiteDomain/[object%20Object]

I assume it's trying to add the urlText to the end of the current domain, like it's a page that I'm specifying instead of a whole new URL.

I added a console.log and it displays urlText just fine. If I click on it from the console, it goes right to the expected website.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the urlText without curly braces? I think it expects the value as a string: window.open(urlTex},'_blank');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add the curly braces around your `urlText` variable since it's within the event callback function. If it were to be used in the JSX then curly braces would be required (like `<div>{urlText}</div>` or `<input type="text" value={urlText} />`) - but since you're calling a function there is no need to wrap the variable name in curly braces.

The error is caused because by wrapping the `urlText` variable in curly braces, you are converting `urlText` to an object: `{ urlText: "foo" }` and thus it appears as `[object%20Object]` in the URL bar since any object converted to a string will be literally `'[object Object]'`.

```js
onClick={(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open(urlText, "_blank");
}}
```

Comment: Yes, you all were right.  window.open(urlText, "_blank");  worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the string urlText directly into the function: `window.open(urlText, '_blank')` without curly brackets.

The curly brackets is syntax to create an object, this function takes in a string argument as its first parameter. So javascript parses your argument into a string [object%20Object], and due to there being no protocol in that it recognises it as a local path.